# using "patern' and "matcher" how can I return all elements not just first one

Tags: java

My task is to create random villain object and write to file. Then I create class that for each created villain will create appropriate superHero and rewrite file to new folder.I use pattern to catch required stats and matcher to create hero object with same stats. However if Villain objects is more than one, my code creates hero only for first one... 
In the attached example code how can I create superHero for each Villain if there is more than one line of villains.
Thanks for help

```
public class ShieldMonitoring {
private static final Pattern VILLAIN_LINE = Pattern.compile("Villain .* with superpower (.*) at level (.*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lines = loadFromFile();

    if (lines.isEmpty()) {

    } else {

        System.out.println(lines.size()-1+" people saved by:");

    }


    SuperHero hero = findHero(lines);

    if(hero != null) {

        try (BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Battlezone/battle-zone-1.txt", true))) {
            output.write("Defeated by");
            output.newLine();
            output.write(hero.toString());
            output.newLine();
            System.out.println(hero.toString());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        new File("Battlezone/battle-zone-1.txt").renameTo(new File("Saved-the-world-again/battle-zone-1.txt"));

    }

}

private static SuperHero findHero(List<String> lines) {
    for (String line : lines) {

        Matcher matcher = VILLAIN_LINE.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String power = matcher.group(1);
            int level = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

            SuperThing superThing = new SuperThing();
            for(SuperHero hero : superThing.getHero()) {
                if(hero.getHeroLevel() == level && hero.getSuperpower().equals(power)) {
                    return hero;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}

public static List<String> loadFromFile() {
    try {
        File VillainFile = new File("Battlezone/battle-zone-1.txt");
        if (!VillainFile.exists()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        try (BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(VillainFile))) {


            return buffReader.lines()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());



        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
SuperHero hero = findHero(lines);
```

In the above line, you are just finding one hero for all the lines/villains. Essentially, if you need to find a hero for every line/villain, you must modify the method to find and return heroes (a list of `SuperHero` objects). So you can modify the above line as:

```
List<SuperHero> hero = findHeroes(lines);
```

And implement the `findHeroes` method similarly, by iterating over the lines, adding a hero to a list and returning the list of heroes as below:

```
private static List<SuperHero> findHeroes(List<String> lines) {
    List<SuperHero> heroes = new ArrayList<SuperHero>();
    for (String line : lines) {

        Matcher matcher = VILLAIN_LINE.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String power = matcher.group(1);
            int level = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

            SuperThing superThing = new SuperThing();
            for(SuperHero hero : superThing.getHero()) {
                if(hero.getHeroLevel() == level && hero.getSuperpower().equals(power)) {
                    heroes.add(hero);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return heroes;
}
```